# Have Landing image fixed and covered as I scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I just want to know how to fix my landing page picture such that as I scroll, the content covers the landing page image. Here is an example of the functionality I want. https://www.libbypeterson.com/

Comment: hey welcome to SO , please do refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

use "background-attachment" attribute

```
.bk-fixed {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

and next time, please structure your question to human-acceptable format